# Visual Studio 2005 VS Visual Studio Express 2012

Tags: javascript, css, vb.net, html, visual-studio-2005

I already have the Pro version of Visual Studio 2005.  (Using only VB.NET, day and night, to write only WindowsForms exe programs for the past 8 years.  100,000s lines of code.)

I now have a need to (finally) write large amounts of code using HTML4, HTML5, JavaScript and CSS.  (I've always just used NotePad, in the past.)

Should I download/install the free Visual Studio Express 2012 instead of using VS2005?

Won't the commercial/pro VS2005 version do far more?   Can (and should) both programs be installed on the same machine?

(I'm using Windows XP on an older 2gb machine.)

Thanks.

Comment: You fail the specs, read the requirements, XP is not going to cut it.

Answer (score 1):

You won't see anything about "won't work with XP" when you download it.  There's really nothing that VS2012E does... that requires Windows 7... but it still does.   The installer also fails to check that you are running XP.  You'll just waste your time downloading... making/wasting a DVD... and installing... and hours of troubleshooting.  Thanks, Microsoft!

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use VS2012E on Windows XP :( Sorry.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/ae2bf77c-36ae-450c-9e1d-d0c481bf24a5/

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2012 will handle newer technologies far better than VS 2005.  While you won't have some of the "pro" features available, the general usage has been upgraded through multiple releases, so many of the standard development tooling is far better.  Depending on what you're doing with HTML 5, the Express tooling may be far nicer than the older Visual Studio release.

That being said, it will not run on your system, as [VS 2012 requires Windows Vista 7 or later](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/compatibility).